Regex expressions any suggestions where i am wrong in my code
Here is my convertor to parce SQL into java Objects.
Basicaly I am getting and sql query with only select part ( without from and select )
select case when nvl(document_type_name,'') in ('-','') then 1 else 0 end as err_status from - bold text is my input
select cast(attr1 as string) as alias1, cast int(*) as alias2 from - bold text is my input
from this intput i have to take
expression part = case when nvl(document_type_name,'') in ('-','') then 1 else 0 end
alias part = err_status
The main problem of my code is that i am using two different regexes, How can i create only one regex for all cases.
This is **right** output i want to get.

[AliasExpr(alias=err_status, expr=case when nvl(document_type_name,'') in ('-','') then 1 else 0 end)]
[AliasExpr(alias=nationkey, expr='nationkey'), AliasExpr(alias=country, expr='name')]
[AliasExpr(alias=alias1, expr=cast(attr1 as string), AliasExpr(alias=alias2, expr=cast int(*))), AliasExpr(alias=alias2, expr=cast int(*))]
[AliasExpr(alias=fp_purpouse_criteria_id, expr='fp_purpouse_criteria_id'), AliasExpr(alias=fp_purpouse_criteria_name, expr='fp_purpouse_criteria_name'), AliasExpr(alias=fp_purpouse_criteria_version_id, expr='fp_purpouse_criteria_version_id'), AliasExpr(alias=dwh_unp_epbs_fp_id, expr='dwh_unp_epbs_fp_id'), AliasExpr(alias=dwh_fp_purposecriteria_level_id, expr='dwh_fp_purposecriteria_level_id'), AliasExpr(alias=dwh_unp_mu_fp_purposes_parent_id, expr='dwh_unp_mu_fp_purposes_parent_id'), AliasExpr(alias=fed_project_id, expr='fed_project_id'), AliasExpr(alias=fp_purposecriteria_level_id, expr='fp_purposecriteria_level_id')]


        String input1 = "case when nvl(document_type_name,'') in ('-','') then 1 else 0 end as err_status".toLowerCase();
        String input2 = "'nationkey' as nationkey, 'name' as country".toLowerCase();
        String input3 = "cast(attr1 as string) as alias1, cast int(*) as alias2".toLowerCase();
        String input4 = "'fp_purpouse_criteria_id' AS fp_purpouse_criteria_id, 'fp_purpouse_criteria_name' AS fp_purpouse_criteria_name, 'fp_purpouse_criteria_version_id' AS fp_purpouse_criteria_version_id, 'dwh_unp_epbs_fp_id' AS dwh_unp_epbs_fp_id, 'dwh_fp_purposecriteria_level_id' AS dwh_fp_purposecriteria_level_id, 'dwh_unp_mu_fp_purposes_parent_id' AS dwh_unp_mu_fp_purposes_parent_id, 'fed_project_id' AS fed_project_id, 'fp_purposecriteria_level_id' AS fp_purposecriteria_level_id".toLowerCase();



public static List<AliasExpr> converter (String input){
        List<AliasExpr> alias = new ArrayList<>();
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s+as\\s+(?![^(]*\\))(\\w+)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            List<String> split = Arrays.asList(input.split(String.valueOf(pattern)));

            if (split.size() > 1) {
                Pattern multiple_regex  = Pattern.compile("(?i)(.+?)\\s+AS\\s+(\\w+)");
                Matcher matcher1 = multiple_regex.matcher(input);
                while (matcher1.find()) {
                    alias.add(
                            new AliasExpr(
                                    matcher1.group(2).replaceAll("^,|,$", "").trim(),
                                    matcher1.group(1).replaceAll("^,|,$", "").trim()));
                }

            }else {
                String firstPart = input.substring(0, matcher.start()).trim();
                String secondPart = matcher.group(1);
                alias.add(new AliasExpr(
                        secondPart.replaceAll("^,|,$", "").trim(),
                        firstPart.replaceAll("^,|,$", "").trim()));
            }
        }
        return alias;
    }

I expect giving me some adives where should i go? or help to refactor my code for better solution

You probably need an SQL parser to parse SQL expressions.

AS is used for a lot of things in SQL, so I doubt your regex will cover all cases.  Also, for what it’s worth, input.split(String.valueOf(pattern)) should be written as pattern.split(input).
